# MariaDB и Python. Каким коннектором воспользоваться?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb

Уважаемое комьюнити! Я начал изучать связку Python и SQL. Возник вопрос следующего плана:

Каким коннектором воспользоваться? Оригинальным от MySQL? Или же драйвером от MariaDB? У меня установлен последний. Насколько я понимаю, коннектор MySQL совместим с MariaDB, но не наоборот.

Есть ли существенные различия в быстродействии при использовании коннектора MySQL и коннектора MariaDB при работе с моей СУБД?

Comment: MariaDB настолько давно отфорковалась от MySQL, что по-хорошему их надо рассматривать как пусть и высокосовместимые, но разные СУБД. А потому "родной" коннектор, несомненно, предпочтительнее совместимого.